# GitLab project templates: Propagate template changes to all repositories that were created from that template

Tags: git, gitlab

I am building [custom group-level project templates](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/custom_project_templates.html) in GitLab which my team will use to initialize new GitLab projects / repositories. These templates contain skeletons for applications, as well as CI/CD configurations (*.gitlab-ci.yml*).

I expect to make small changes to those templates in the future. Is there an elegant way to propagate changes in a template to all the repositories that were created from that template?

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible at the time, why not using a repo as a template and fork it so you can sync it if necessary ?

Comment: @Reynadan My GitLab project templates also contain things like GitLab CI variables, branch protection setups, etc. which need to be copied to the new project as well. So, using only forks would rob me off that advantage.

Answer (score 2):

Once the template has been used to initialize a new GitLab project, there is no more interaction with it.

Any evolution so said template should be completed by a GitLab CI script which would:

- list projects
- check if they "look like" they have been created from a template (to my knowledge, the [GitLab Project API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html) does not include the "template ID" for projects created from a template)
- apply programmatically those change/evolution.

In other words, there does not seem to be an "automagic" way to propagate changes from a template to its repositories.

---

The [OP Elisabeth Strunk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10917711/elisabeth-strunk)  refers to a possible implementation with [Roger D. Winans](https://github.com/solvaholic)'s [script](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/23528#discussioncomment-3240734) as [`.github/workflows/sync-from-template.yml`](https://github.com/solvaholic/template/blob/2ba4ed5a94f0fb60b542f8a08e0d6e7e1c9bd05e/.github/workflows/sync-from-template.yml).
It does copy files from the template onto the target clone.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I was really hoping that there would be a more elegant way.  I am thinking about implementing something similar to what _solvaholic_ proposes [here](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/23528#discussioncomment-3240734)

Comment: @ElisabethStrunk Interesting script indeed. I have included your comment and a reference to Roger's script in the answer for more visibility.